# Can I remove any need for dialogs when running a Java applet in the browser?

Tags: java, security, applet

I am running a Java applet in the browser. However, each browser displays a warning of

```
"This applet may not be trusted... etc."
```

and the user is allowed to click `Run Anyway` or `Cancel`. This is built in to the browsers / Java configuration. (If the user is running on a security level > Medium, the applet is simply blocked.)

Is there a way for me to sign the applet in such a way that no dialogs appear? Or will they still appear even if the applet is "trusted"?

Comment: Can't be done. Even if it's signed, you may still have dialogs appearing. You could consider using Java Web Start, but I'm not sure if this will solve the problem entirely

Comment: @MadProgrammer  JWS will still come with all the Java based warnings, though it will (for **free-floating** apps.) avoid the browser warnings and blocks.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's what I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot.

It is no longer generally considered safe to run Java in the browser. The Java plugin has implemented [a number of security measures](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html) that will display a spectrum of different security warnings depending on the user's current Java security level and the signed status of the applet, but **no settings will disable the warnings entirely** (short of settings which block the applet from loading at all). Additionally, some web browsers and operating systems have begun to apply their own, separate restrictions to Java applets. For instance, Google Chrome will display a warning bar before attempting to load the Java plugin, and Mac OS X does not install Java at all by default.

If you have any choice in the matter, avoid writing Java applets. Like many other older web technologies, like Shockwave and Quicktime, they are part of the past, not the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - you've made me the bearer of bad news.